# Unable to use older version of play services through gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I need to use the LocationClient class which is available only until play-services 5.0. So this is what I try in my build.gradle :

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'

The error I get on compiling is :

> Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+

It works well when I try :

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'

But then I lose access to LocationClient, and my code breaks.

I tried both mavenCentral() and jcenter() as repositories, but doesn't help. I am on gradle 2.2.1, with gradle plugin 1.0.0 and Android studio 1.0.2. I have enabled Android support repo (v11), support library (doesn't matter, but I am on 21.0.3), Google Play services (v22), Google Play services for Froyo (v12), Google repository (v15).

What surprised me is that when I go to my_sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services, **I see folders with older versions of play-services (like 5.0.89) with the pom and .aar file**. It's just not being used. Here is the content from pom.xml for 5.0.89 in my local machine :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>play-services</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.89</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
      <version>19.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I also used compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0' to make sure if support-v4 is not creating a problem, but still the issue is not resolved.

The last option I have is to manually use the .aar in my libs. But then I lose the advantage of having a build system.

Comment: Have you tried exactly `com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89`?

Comment: That's definitely the sdk path that Android Studio is using? What with the forced sdk relocation around v0.9 or so, maybe it's possible you ended up with duplicate sdks somehow.

Comment: @stkent : I have only one copy of sdk. I double checked project's local.properties

Comment: It gets Play Services from the Google repository, which is in the extras/google/m2repository directory you looked in; it doesn't look in MavenCentral/jcenter (the Android Gradle plugin is hardcoded to look in the SDK for this). I know you've checked it, but something weird about your SDK installation seems the likeliest explanation. You could add your build.gradle file to your question, though I'm not sure what you could be doing in there that could cause these exact symptoms.